# I need to know how to copy data of specify columns from one list to another using 1 common column in sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, moss2007enterprisesearch

I need to know how to copy data of specify columns from one list to another using 1 common column in sharepoint 2007. For e.g. In one list i have employeenumber,contact number and mail address. And I want to copy contact number and mail address to another list based on employeenumber. Please let me know how to do that as i am new in sharepoint.

Comment: I need help regarding where to start from..

Comment: There are many ways to reach this goal. Please describe your requirement, with a higher point of view.

Comment: Currently I have written a program to transfer the data from one list to another. It works fine for now. But im not sure whether its the right way. I just want to know if there is an alternate way so that i can confirm my results. The issue is common column in the lists. As the employee number refers to an active directory. The employee number chosen in one list for some employees is location\EmpNo and in another list the same Emp No. is reflected as just EmpNo. E.g. List 1: EmpNo. : Mumbai\12345 List 2: EmpNo. : 12345.And I want the data to be transferred properly inspite of this issue.

Comment: Please help me with this

Comment: I have written a code that excepts the dat from excel sheet and adds the Employee details in the list if the Employee number matches for above problem it works well for a while and then suddenly throws THREAD WAS ABORTED EXCEPTION. Query written is DRV is the Datarow view taken from Excelsheet fieldValue1 = Convert.ToString(drv["Employee Number"]); SPQuery query = new SPQuery(); query.Query = string.Format("<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=' Employee _x0020_Number' /><Value Type='Text'>" + fieldValue1 + "</Value></Eq></Where>");

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in many ways, Let me tell same scenario in different form.

**Case 1: you have list in same site web**

- get web object
- make 2 spList objects
- using 2 foreach traverse through list collection
- assign values.

**Case 2: you have list in different site web**

- get web object
- get source list object
- get destination web object
- get destination  list object
- using 2 foreach traverse through list collection
- assign values.